# how to check array next index is exists or not in php?

Tags: php

I want to check array next index if exists or not in php. The content is dynamic so I cannot compare the string because I would not know what will be the next array value like "story4" or it could be "mogli-story".

```
<?php
$story = array("story1","stroy2","story3")
?>
```

If the next index is available, then print next index. if the next index is not available then it print Story0 the first index of the array. I am trying to do like below but not succeeded.

```
<p>The next story is: <?=((isset($story[$i]))?$story[$i]:'$story[0]');?><p>
```

Comment: `$story[$i + 1]` would get the next value, am I missing something?

Comment: If you are just assigning values without specifying the index, you can also check against `count($story)` which is the end of the array rather than if an index is empty.

Comment: @Grumpy Thanks for the reply. What is $story[$i + 1] won't exists? How to check that?

Comment: @Sarah Same way you are checking if the current one exists, `isset($story[$i + 1])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but maybe this will help.

Arrays are indexed from 0, meaning this code:

```
<?php
    $story = array("story1","stroy2","story3")
?>
```

Has *3* indexes, 0, 1, and 2.

I'm not sure how you've defined `$i` in your code, but I think this is what you want:

```
<p>The next story is: <?=isset($story[$i + 1]) ? $story[$i + 1] : $story[0];?><p>
```

(Note, most of the parenthesis you had are not needed.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `next` and `current`

```
<p>The next story is: <?=((next($story))?current($story):'$story[0]');?><p>
```

function `next` move element to next, `current` return current element, if you array end, `next` return false. if php7

```
<p>The next story is: <?=((next($story))??'$story[0]');?><p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this completely answers your question, but you could use a foreach-loop:

```
<?php
$story = array("story1","stroy2","story3");

foreach($story as $entry) {
        print($entry.PHP_EOL);
}
```

If you need to dynamically check for the array keys, you could use [array-keys](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php) or [array-key-exists](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-key-exists.php)